# How to create dictionary from predefined keys and values as the list?

Tags: python

Let's say that I have 3 users and keys will be: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]. I would like to create a dictionary with the list of zeroes but the number of the zeroes in each key should match number of users, so I want to have it like that:
{"a": [0,0,0], "b": [0,0,0], "c": [0,0,0], "d", [0,0,0]}

What is the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
users=['u','v','w']
d={k:len(users)*[0] for k in ['a','b','c','d']}
print(d)
```

gives

```
{'a': [0, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 0, 0], 'c': [0, 0, 0], 'd': [0, 0, 0]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as I expected :)

Answer (score 0):

```
l =  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
result = {i:[0,0,0] for i in l}
```

will give you the desired dict `{'a': [0, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 0, 0], 'c': [0, 0, 0], 'd': [0, 0, 0]}`